# Como unir imagens no PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Galera , como eu poderia juntar essas 3 imagens em uma só para realizar o download dela , meu código está assim :

```
<div class="imgtmn"> <?php echo "<img id='imgpos1' src='img/$cod.png' alt='' />"?></div>
          <div class="imgtmn"> <?php echo "<img id='imgpos2' src='img/$cod.png' alt='' />"?></div>
           <div class="imgtmn"> <?php echo "<img id='imgpos' src='img/$cod.png' alt='' />"?></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Não sei exatamente a forma que você deseja juntar as imagens, mas criei um código para colocar uma imagem do lado da outra... ou seja, juntar duas imagens em uma imagem.

Deixei alguns comentários no código para ajudar a entender.

Primeira imagem:

[image: Angular]

Segunda imagem:

[image: Spring]

Usando o código para juntar as imagens:

[image: Angular + Spring]

Código:

```php
<?php

// Foto Angular
$img_angular = imagecreatefrompng($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "angular.png");
$img_angular_largura = imagesx($img_angular);
$img_angular_altura = imagesy($img_angular);

// Foto Spring
$img_spring = imagecreatefrompng($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "spring.png");
$img_spring_largura = imagesx($img_spring);
$img_spring_altura = imagesy($img_spring);

if ($img_angular_altura >= $img_spring_altura) {
    $img_altura = $img_angular_altura;
} else {
    $img_altura = $img_spring_altura;
}

// Cria uma imagem de transparente com o tamanho das duas imagens (imagem x do lado da imagem y)
$img = imagecreatetruecolor($img_spring_largura + $img_angular_largura, $img_altura);
imagefill($img, 0, 0, imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 0, 0, 0, 127));
imagesavealpha($img, true);

// Insere a primeira imagem (angular) na imagem criada (para juntar as duas imagens)
$img_largura = 0;
imagecopyresampled($img, $img_angular, $img_largura, 0, 0, 0, $img_angular_largura, $img_angular_altura, $img_angular_largura, $img_angular_altura);

// Insere a segunda imagem (spring) a partir do último pixel que a primeira imagem ocupou
$img_largura = $img_angular_largura;
imagecopyresampled($img, $img_spring, $img_largura, 0, 0, 0, $img_spring_largura, $img_spring_altura, $img_spring_largura, $img_spring_altura);

// Cria a imagem
imagepng($img, $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "angular_e_spring.png");
```